# How to parse XML in JavaScript from Google

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, weather

I want to parse this XML Document http://www.google.de/ig/api?weather=Braunschweig,%20Deutschland I want to be able to read out condition, temp_c and humidity. All this I want to do inside of JavaScript without using any server sided scripts such as PHP and I want it to work on modern browsers as well as IE7 and if without many problems IE6 
EDIT: 
A solution without a framework would be ideal

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are working on a page hosted on google.de — you can't.

The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents JS running in a webpage on your site from accessing a document on a remote site.

You have to involve a server side process in order to either convert the XML into a format that you can handle remotely (such as JSON-P, which [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) will do for you) or relay the data through your own server with a server side process accessible in the same origin as the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial at Ajaxian on how to parse XML with jQuery
http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajaxian-featured-tutorial-parsing-xml-with-jquery
hope it helps

edit: the tutorial actually is here: http://blog.reindel.com/2007/09/24/jquery-and-xml-revisited/

Answer (score 1):

I've had some luck parsing XML in javascript with code like:

```
var xmlDoc = this.req.responseXML.documentElement;
var tStatus = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("status")[0].firstChild.data;
var tOtherURL = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("otherurl")[0].firstChild.data;
var tRows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rows")[0].firstChild.data;
```

Keep in mind that I don't really know Javascript and I cargo-cult'ed this from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) and Opera the solution is very easy: They have builtin XPath support. So you just [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate) an XPath expression on the DOM of the XML response.

With IE there's more work to do. Someone else asked basically the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178016/problem-selecting-html-elements-with-xpath-in-internet-explorer) before and the reasonable answer is: You'll need to employ JavaScript library that will allow you to use XPath. Otherwise you end up writing your problem-specific parsing code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jQuery plugin that parses XML pretty easily. It works in all Yahoo A grade browsers and comes with filtering, limit and callback options.

It might be a solution to consider: http://jparse.kylerush.net/

Answer (score -2):

I think I found a tutorial (its in german though) http://www.aboutwebdesign.de/awd/content/1124893836.shtml