# Javascript XML parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, feed

What is the best JavaScript library to parse XML/RSS/Atom feeds?

Is there something like Python [Feed parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) but then for JavaScript ?

thanks,

Pero

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323982/how-to-parse-xml-in-javascript-from-google

Comment: Define your criteria for "Best" ?

Comment: no criteria, what do YOU recommend as a good xml parsing library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JKL parseXML is an awesome toolkit for that.

http://www.kawa.net/works/js/jkl/parsexml-e.html