# PhoneGap XML Parser?

Tags: cordova

I've been searching a really really long time for an XML Parser usable with PhoneGap. Is there a way to use this http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file Parser in my PhoneGap App or is there a way to make it compatible. Please help!

Comment: You should use javascript xml parsing. I think PhoneGap use javascript.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you use PhoneGap to develop an iPhone app, so you are using an javascript framework, not native right?

Answer (score 6):

Rule of thumb about Phonegap: for the most part anything you can do in the browser **using Javascript**, you can do in Phonegap **using Javascript** with a couple of nice bonus API calls. [See Phonegap API Doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/) and [Phonegap community plugin repository](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins) (Note if you absolutely need some additional functionality from iPhone or Android or whatever platform the repo would be the place to go asking about it).

So Javascript XML is what you are looking for.

- [An introduction to parsing xml in javascript](http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript)
- [Explaination of xml parsing natively with javascript](http://www.mindlence.com/WP/?page_id=114)
- [A list of xml parsing javascript librarys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031231/javascript-xml-parsing)

Or alternatively if you have options for formats, [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is probably your best bet.