# How to implement XML parsing in Phonegap/Android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing, cordova

I have searched the web regarding XML parsing in Phonegap/Android. But I haven't found any sort of useful post.

I only found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306394/phonegap-xml-parser).

This tells how to implement in **Javascript.** But I would like to know what is the procedure to implement it in a Phonegap/Android project?

Answer (score 1):

see this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

you can use jQuery..

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.